# IE11 error: Login causes Double GET call, state: wating

Tags: authentication, post, spring-security, get, internet-explorer-11

IE11 cause weird behaviour I've never seen before, i've talked about it with co-workers and noone got a real clue of what is going on.

When login with firefox, chrome , ie6 and ie8 login of the web page works fine as always, a migration to Ie11  is causing several problems one of them is double call on method of spring security authentication and get calls of .java, causing severe login errors (not being able to login, showing sections of web not according to the permits of the user...).

Project is based on jsp some js an jquery, back uses spring core, etc...
cache control set no no-cache

Double call on spring security auth and errors of login was solved adding a a return false; or event.preventdefault() on the submit button, but it still causes on Ie11 a double call on my login method on the back .java as showed on the ie11 console. I've got no real clue what could be causing this, I've changed paremeters added/modified properties of the form-login in the spring security config.xml but i didn't fix the thing.

web-security conf.xml

```
    <anonymous enabled="true" />

    <form-login authentication-failure-url="/sirrhh/?error=1"
        login-page="/comun/controlLogin.jsp" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        default-target-url="/sirrhh/loginOK" always-use-default-target="true" />

    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
        logout-success-url="/sirrhh/?error=0" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/sirrhh/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/comun/controlLogin.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/sirrhh/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/comun/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />

</http>
```

indexLogin.jsp has a username/passwrd and submit button with

form method="POST" action=c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'>

and

button name="bupdate" id="bupdate" class="buttonListado" style="width: 85px;"  type="submit" return false;">

screenshot of network console of ie11 response with 2 calls to a .java method with one of them on waiting status

[bad IE11 network response with 2 calls to a .java method with one of them on waiting status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsXiL.jpg)

second screenshot: good network response code 200 on Chrome with only one call to the .java method

[good network response code 200 on Chrome with only one call to the .java method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd1yI.jpg)

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: I found that, this issue can occur if you are passing the wrong type attribute value. MSIE browsers use Mime sniffing on content and compare that with the content's digital signature. If the response content-type does not match the type attribute value of the request. MSIE will resend the request for the data with the mime type determined by the initial response.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, never heard of such thing before  and really don't know how to apply that as the request type is done entirely via spring security and the response is a spring springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView class type obj.of the same login.jsp that made the request.

Comment: Generally we pass the type in the HTML code. Not sure how to do it in spring security.